# Casting char * as int gives strange error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I've run into a slightly strange problem - I have a char array that I want to output as hex. I don't mind casting as int, but when I do, a lot of f's are added in front of some of the numbers. I have this code do my output for me:

```
for (int i = 0; i<(bmp.BytesPerRow*bmp.Height);i++) // once per color per pixel
{
    if(i%3==0) // one line between each pixel
    {
        cout << "\n";
    }

int tmp = (int) bmp.Raster[i];
cout << "\nbmp.Raster[" << i << "]": " << hex << tmp;

}
```

and my output looks like this:

```
bmp.Raster[0]: ffffffff
bmp.Raster[1]: ffffffff
bmp.Raster[2]: ffffffff

bmp.Raster[3]: 40
bmp.Raster[4]: 20
bmp.Raster[5]: ffffffe0

bmp.Raster[6]: 40
bmp.Raster[7]: ffffffe0
bmp.Raster[8]: 20
etc...
```

and frankly I don't get it. I could understand if it was

```
ff
ff
ff

40
20
e0

etc...
```

and I could understand if the f's were appended to everything (I'd figure it was an artifact of the casting process and just discard the first 6 outputs) but only to some? I don't get it.

Additional info:

bmp.Raster is from the class CRaster[1] kindly provided by Juan Soulie

IDE is Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express which automatically does #include "tchar.h", but I've tried commenting that library out and the oddity persists.

[1]http://www.cplusplus.com/files/winbmp.zip

EDIT: Some of you are providing suggestions for solutions - and I appreciate that - but mostly I'm asking here if somebody knows what the devil is going on?

EDIT AGAIN: Problem was resolved by James Kanze.

The loop has been changed to:

```
for (int i = 0; i<(bmp.BytesPerRow*bmp.Height);i++) // once per color per pixel
{
    if(i%3==0) // one line between each pixel
    {
        cout << "\n";
    }

uint8_t tmp0 = (uint8_t)bmp.Raster[i];
uint16_t tmp1 = (uint16_t)tmp0;
cout << "\nbmp.Raster[" << i << "]": " << hex << tmp1;

}
```

and the output is now correct.

Comment: int tmp = bmp.Raster[i] & 0xff;

Comment: Yeah, that would make the output correct but I'd still be wondering what the devil was going on. I hate solutions that work by bypassing errors - Like I said, if it was on every output I'd just discard it but because it's only on some, I'm afraid that there's an underlying issue.

Comment: It is not bypassing errors. sign bit will always propagate to higher bits.

Comment: @John: In the little perfectionist world in my head, not accounting for sign bits and just ignoring it, hoping that it will never be important /is/ a bypass. If I was under time pressure, I'd probably have done what you suggested but I wanted to find out why this was happening, more than I wanted to solve it.

Comment: `int` variable reads `0xffffffff` as -1 and `char` variable reads `0xff` as -1 which is 255 for `int`.So your data has not changed since you are only care about the least significant byte of int which is same as `char`. Your case is all about displaying data in Hex byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that plain char's on your machine are signed.  (If
you're not too concerned about portability, both g++ and VC++
have options to make plain char unsigned.)   You need to first
cast the char to unsigned char, then cast the unsigned char to
int.  Or, if you can change the data structures you're
outputting, change them to use unsigned char; that seems more
appropriate for things like bitmaps anyway.

Comment: Yup, that worked. uint8_t tmp0 = (uint8_t) bmp.Raster[i] followed by uint16_t tmp1 = (uint16_t)tmp0 gives the correct values in tmp1. EDIT: Presumably it also gives the correct values in tmp0 but outputting those still gives me characters rather than hex. But thank you.

Comment: Right.  The cast to `unsigned char` gives you the "right" value (non-negative), and the cast to a non-character integral type causes the value to be converted, rather than being treated as a character encoding itself.

Answer (score 1):

Not this:

```
int tmp = (int) bmp.Raster[i];
```

but this:

```
int          tmp = (unsigned int) bmp.Raster[i];   // OR
unsigned int tmp =                bmp.Raster[i];
```

might work.

When you cast the byte value to a (signed) int, the sign bit (the high-order bit) of the byte gets propagated to fill the upper part of the integer. So a byte of (say) 0x80 becomes an int of something like 0xffffff80. Unsigned arithmetic yields the behavior you want.

Comment: for completeness, surely you want to fix your last line to: `unsigned int tmp = static_cast<usnigned int>(bmp.Raster[i]);` :)

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of your suggestions worked - and nor does static_cast

Answer (score 0):

Use this line:

```
unsigned char tmp = bmp.Raster[i];
```

instead of:

```
int tmp = (int) bmp.Raster[i];
```

It might works.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. Unsigned char is output as char i.e. as actual ascii characters.

Comment: There is something wrong. you can print output as hex, by calling the printf method. also i think the output of this line is decimal:
`code`cout << "\nbmp.Raster[" << i << "]": " << hex << tmp1;`code`
use this:
`code`printf("\nbmp.Raster[%2x]", bmp.Raster[i]);`code`